# How to format a list of int into a Json object

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, json, list

I have a list of integers coming from the front-end:

```
List<int> IDs = [1,76,103];
```

How can I format this in C# into a Json object while adding a name to each value, e.g :

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1
  },
  {
    "ID": 76
  },
  {
    "ID": 103
  }
]
```

Comment: JSON is not a format.  It is serialized data, so serialize the list

Comment: The serialization gives this : [1,2067,2081,2087,2091,2092,2093], but I want a name for each value, e.g : [{"ID":1},{"ID":76},{"ID":103}]

Comment: Then you need a class to hold the integers, the property would be named `ID`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this just by using Linq and then serialize like this :

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(IDs.Select(a => new
            {
                ID = a
            }));
```

Comment: I think your solution is simplest and better.

Answer (score 2):

Something like (see https://dotnetfiddle.net/NGAJKu):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var theReturn = new List<MyObject>{
            new MyObject{ID = 1},
            new MyObject{ID = 2},
            new MyObject{ID = 3}
        };
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(theReturn));
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public int ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
[{"ID":1},{"ID":2},{"ID":3}]
```